# Access root controller action from view inside area does not work with area = ""

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am in the view inside an area called "Application".

In this view I have this Link:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff","Account", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "",  id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

This ActionLink refers to a Root Controller "AccountController" with an action "LogOff".

When I submit the form the browser shows this in the URL bar:

http://localhost:61774/Application/Account/LogOff

But this route does not exist because it does **NOT** look in the Root controller although I set `area = ""`

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29) of `Html.BeginForm()` which is adding `area` as a html attribute, not a route value. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29) to add route values

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff","Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
```